# Open Street Maps - Drawing a line based on given nodes

Tags: routes, drawing, openstreetmap

Along with a friend, we have started a fun little side-project to test what we have learned these last few months. We decided we would do a simple map navigation program that would take an input from a user (starting place + desired location) and draw the route based on the Open Street Maps data we have extracted. For our first attempt we assume the user is in a car and implemented in Java a k-shortest path to find the route between them. I also used a short algorithm to find the nearest node to a user's present and desired location, which while not perfect, works neatly for the level we hope to achieve. And it's working really well, the routes given over to all test maps are always valid and generally fast, a few times even optimal. The results are returned to an ArrayList of Nodes(id,ref,long,lat).

What we now want is to be able to input the starting-node,finishing-node and all the found routing nodes in a map view in a web page. Our general idea is that the user will be able to click two points at the map , and a red line will be drawn along the nodes-ways our javal class has returned. How do you propose we do this? I have succesfully used js to center the user's desired map and zoom level, as well as a central point, but the live-line drawing has proven elusive. I do not ask for a solution, as this would actually go against the whole project's idea, but I could really use some pointers as to what resources I shall be looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at one of the many [online routers for OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters) in order to get an idea how to draw a route in a web page. Alternatively you can generate a GPX file and use [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or a similar library to draw it on a map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I shall be checking it within the hour

Comment: Thank you a thousand times!!! Took a fast crash GPX course,and managed to actually finish not just this problem, but the whole tasks since I answered! I will return to give rep once I am +15, and thanks again for your most timeply answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add lines using **OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString()** to an Open Street Map.  I've tested this out and it works okay.

```
  locations = [[-77.3861, 38.9695], [-122.1781, 37.459], [-122.1781, 37.459], [-122.1781, 37.459], [-122.1781, 37.459], [-122.1826, 37.3762], [-122.1781, 37.459], [-122.1826, 37.3762], [-122.1826, 37.3762], [-122.1826, 37.3762]];
  var lines = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Lines Overlay");
  var coordinates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    coordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]).transform(fromProjection, toProjection));
  }
  var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(coordinates));
  lines.addFeatures(feature);
  map.addLayer(lines);
```

Additional API help is at:
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html